# Android Page Flip For Web View

Tags: android

Now I am trying page flip animation for web view in android

visit http://github.com/harism/android_page_curl and you can get information on how to page flip, but it is applicable only for images. What would I have to do to apply this for web view?

Comment: Were you able to complete this. I am also trying to do page flip using webview. Please inform me whether it is feasible or not.

Comment: @Karthi have you got solution for this? i too need some guidance for page curl effect in webview.if you got solution please post some reference for this.

Answer (score 1):

i had also facing same problem so I'm implementing below link but its not like page curl but full fill my requirement hope your also.

https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip

hope use full for you.

Comment: Hey does this work for webview in android? How to link the webview code with this flipper?